# Loading page in WPF

Tags: wpf

Guys, I have a basic WPF application. Contains App.xaml as always and a Mainwindow.xaml.
I've created also some pages like page1/2/3. I want to load for example page1.xaml in mainwindow.xaml. Is this possible? And also want to close it so the content of mainwindow.xaml will stay in there.

I dont want this to be a navigation application with the left/right arrows at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a frame to your main page and load the pages on it.

Comment: how to load that frame in center of screen ?

Answer (score 18):

I came here to add that there are many ways to load the pages into the frame:

By setting the source (as @Shift mentioned)

```
frame1.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

By setting the Content:

```
frame1.Content= new Page1();
```

By using the `NavigationService`:

```
frame1.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
```

Comment: also do NOT forget to remove width and height properties inside the Page.xaml.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a frame and setting the source for the frame like makes my day :)

```
frame1.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call below navigate function from inside any control or verification area.Page1 is the new page.So it opens like a new window from the application.

```
    NavigationWindow navigationWdw = new NavigationWindow();
    navigationWdw.Height = this.Height;
    navigationWdw.Width = this.Width;
    navigationWdw.Show();
    navigationWdw.Navigate(new Page1());
```